# Display a multiline text properly from MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, display

I have a problem to display properly a text using PHP.

The row 'content' of the MySQL database contains this :

```
Item1 : value1
Item2 : value2
Item3 : value3

Total value
```

So I do a foreach like this :

```
foreach($connection->query('SELECT * FROM table') as $row)
```

And I display the content like this :

```
echo $row['content'];
```

But it returns a result like this :

```
Item1 : value1 Item2 : Value2 Item3 : Value3 Total value
```

And I would like to display it with one item per line, not all the items on the same line.

Thanks !

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `nl2br` which replaces line breaks with `<br>`

```
echo nl2br($row['content']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the line breaks after your data

```
echo $row['content'].'<br>';
```

Comment: This can't work because all the lines are in one $row['content'] so It's useless to add a <br> after this. Thanks anyway, this is solved with nl2br.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
echo $row['content']."<br>";
```